# How to make Compound Adjectives

Tags: grammar

I would like to find an easy explanation of how to make compound adjectives. Actually, what I want is a functional way or structure which can help me make it on my own. I read the sentences I have made, but I can't make them sound like these examples: *he is left-handed*, *he is kind-hearted*.

Here are some sentences which I tried to make:

> When I was younger, I had some trouble making ideas which led me to nothing.

meaning: Ideas which make trouble

> He is a player making person.

meaning: He can teach everyone how to play

> This is a well organized schedule.

meaning: some good made decision.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already seem to know what [compound adjectives](http://www.englishexercises.org/makeagame/viewgame.asp?id=8591#a) are. They can be created by various combinations: adjective+noun+ed (red-haired), noun+past participle (sun-dried), noun+noun (part-time), number+noun (5-day), adjective +noun (deep-sea). The only question is do you use a hyphen, or not. Some compound adjectives have become one word over time. How do you know? Checking the dictionary would be best.

So let's consult ODO:

1. **[troublemaking](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/troublemaker?q=trouble-making#troublemaker__8)** - derived from troublemaker
2. This one is not recognised by dictionaries - but as an alternative you could always use *coach*
3. **[well-organised](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/well-organized?q=well+organised)**

Comment: Thank you for helping. This sentences could be correct. Like .It's a two doored car or It's a two-door car.

Comment: @English Sorry, I haven't seen your comment up until now. You're welcome :-). It would be a two-door car or a 2-door car (same as a 5-day weather forecast).